# Laravel 5.3: Creating a PostCommentsController for a Blog

Tags: php, database, laravel, controller

I'm creating a Blog which is going to have Posts, Categories, Comments and CommentReplies.

At the moment I'm having the following in the

**PostCommentsController.php**

```
public function show($id)
{
     $post = Post::findOrFail($id);     
     $comments = $post->blog_comments;
     return view('admin.comments.show', compact('comments'));
}
```

My problem is, I've changed the column inside of the table Post for postID, which is different than the expected in Laravel post_id while using the $id, right?

How can I proceed in this case to make this work?

Comment: you mean your primary index changed from id to postID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I am assuming you have model post.php, BlogComment.php.
In the model file post.php

```
public function blog_comments()
{
  return $this->hasMany(BLogComments::class,'postID')
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Sure, I'm having this inside of Post model:

`
public function comments(){


        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');


    }


Will readjust for all of the functions in the following way and let you know the result ASAP:

public function comments(){


        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'postID');


    }`

Comment: just pass the second arrgument of as PostID, otherwise it will take the laravel default as you stated tableName_id (post_id)

Comment: Glad to help :). please mark this as accepted and upvote this, if this solved your problem, because accepted answer will help other people to solve their problem who visits this website and  if they got the same problem. thanks :)

Comment: I've done that, but my reputation is still not high enough to count :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you can select primary key in any model's class, just need change variable

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id'; // For you case it will be 'post_id'
```

Comment: class Post extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'blog_posts';
    protected $primaryKey = 'blogPostID';